# Border-Radius is not Aligning Properly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div with rounded corners. Inside this div contains additional content that will fill up the height of this div. I've noticed that there is some visual corruption at each corner of the rounded div. It looks to me that the corner of the outer div is lightly larger than the inner div. According to my code, the border-radius of both divs should be identical.

Example of issue: http://jsfiddle.net/MRZaF/4/

Image of issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMHtk.jpg

```
<div class="a-a">
    <div class="a-b">Content in here</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="b-a">
    <div class="b-b">Content in here</div>
</div>

div.a-a { background:red; border-radius:10px; width:400px; }
div.a-b { background:aqua; border-radius:10px; height:200px; }
div.b-a { background:red; border-radius:10px; width:400px; overflow:hidden; }
div.b-b { background:aqua; width:400px; height:200px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of option to do this.
***First option***: Slightly increase the border-radius of parent container

```
div.a-a 
{ 
  background:red;  
  border-radius:13px; 
  width:400px; 
}
```

***Second option***: Remove the border-radius from parent element and just use it for child element and set the background none.

```
div.a-a 
{ 
  background:none;  
  width:400px; 
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MRZaF/8/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't put it under put it on top and you wont get that.

div.a-a { background:red; border-radius:10px; width:400px; }
div.a-b { background:aqua; border-radius:10px; height:200px; }

div.b-a { background:red; border-radius:10px; width:400px; overflow:hidden; }
div.b-b { background:aqua; border-radius:10px; width:400px; height:200px;}

jsfiddle.net/MRZaF/5/

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: More of some additional error tracing than an answer & +1 for interesting question**

Yup you're right. There's some kind of minimal corruption, at least pretty visible when you look at it in the browser at 100% zoom level. However, the more you zoom in, the smaller the bug gets; at 500% like 1/10th of a pixel. Your css is correct, so I assume this must be a browser-rendering issue. I don't immediatly find any issue about it in the chrome bug list https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list though.

However, should you really want to hide those overlapping corners, you can still have a workaround by setting a `margin: -0.6px -0.6px;` and a `width: parents width + margin*2` for the child. I don't know, maybe screen matters as well as to the error margin. And Sachin's workarounds work as well of course.

I updated your test case:
http://jsfiddle.net/MRZaF/7/
with some different values to trace the error margin. It seems like at 100% browser view, the difference is about 0.5px from the 'real' positioning, then when you zoom in to say 500%, it gets narrower and narrower.